# How do I navigate to another screen from a login screen with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, swiftui

I want to navigate from a splash/login view to a home view without the possibility of going back unless the user restarts the application using SwiftUI.  I know I can use a navigation link and SwiftUI will present a back button.  Is there a way to go from view to view without the back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to present a view, you can look at this [article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets)

On the contrary if the concern is not to show the back button, on the home view one can hide the back button using the configuration like

`.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`

Comment: HI and thanks for your quick response.  I think I found what I was looking for. https://www.blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-bindableobject